# Sort a column that has multiple data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm importing a csv file which has a column like this:
`Col A = 5.4 (Text/Text/Text), 3.1 (Text/Text), 1.2 (Text/Text), 10.12 (Text)`

How can I count how many items have a value greater than 3.1 ?

I've tried the following code:

```
data = (data['A']>3.1).value_counts()
```

But of course, I have a problem with float and string. I'm not allowed to delete that text. I need just to count the lines that match a specific criteria.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Split your string and retrieve the first element of it (see str.split() doc). Then transform this string into float (see float(str) doc).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using the csv module and the pathlib one.

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

def count(path: Path) -> int:
    tot: list = []
    with open(path, "r", newline="") as op:
        reader = csv.reader(op, delimiter=",")
        data = [line for line in reader]
        for values in data:
            for value in values:
                if float(value) > 3.1:
                    tot.append(value)
        return len(tot)
```

The path can be specified with `Path("path/to/file.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'A': ["5.4 (Text/Text/Text)", "3.1 (Text/Text)", "1.2 (Text/Text)", "10.12 (Text)"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Step 2: Split the text and the numbers with split

```
df['B']=df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" "))
```

Step 3: Split number

```
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Step 4: Count values above 3.1

```
criteria = 3.1
(df['C'].astype(float)>criteria).sum()
```

Step 5: Count values below or the same as criteria

```
(df['C'].astype(float)<=criteria).sum()
```

Comment: And how can i see the end result ? I think that is wrong to add the following lines: data = (data['C'].astype(float)>7).count()  and then print (data)

Comment: Yes, you should use sum() instead of count() and it will work correctly. (df['C'].astype(float)>3.1) will show you whether a value is above 3.1 true or false.

Comment: Great! And for the rest of them, how can i retrieve the number of values that didn't match the criteria ?

Comment: You could use the <= criteria like: (df['C'].astype(float)<=3.1).sum()

Comment: data = (data['C'].astype(float)<3.1).sum()
--> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

###And the code...###
data['B']=data['A'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" "))#
data['C'] = data['B'].apply(lambda x: x[0])#
data = (data['C'].astype(float)>=6.9).sum()#
print(data)#
data = (data['C'].astype(float)<3.1).sum()#
astype(float)>=6.9).sum()#
print(data)

Comment: The ideea is that i want to count and display on the screen how many values match the criteria and how many values doesn't match the criteria.